# What kinds of runtime errors can Haskell have?

Tags: haskell, runtime-error

I've read that Haskell can actually have runtime errors, despite being statically typed and functional. But, no one says *what* runtime errors those might be. Anyone know?

Comment: `undefined`, `error ...`, not enough memory, exceptions. using partial functions outside their value domain (e.g. `head []`)

Comment: Simple examples are arithmetic errors related to input data. Static typing cannot find these, e.g. division by zero when the operands are input data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the runtime exceptions may be throw by the standard libraries (the `base` package) are defined in [Control.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#t:Exception) and [GHC.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Exception.html).

`error` is a function defined in GHC.Err (based on GHC.Exception) as

```
error :: [Char] -> a
error s = raise# (errorCallException s)
```

It throws an `ErrorCall` exception and print an error message to the stderr if isn't catched by some handler, most of the run-time exceptions raised by pure functions in `base` are implemented by `error`.

A few examples:

`undefined`, a placeholder for code yet to be implemented, is defined as

```
undefined :: a
undefined = error "undefined"
```

It will pass the compilation step due to it's type and will raise an exception when it's evaluated at run-time.

The GHC standard library exports some partial functions by historical reasons, e.g. `head`:

```
head                    :: [a] -> a
head (x:_)              =  x
head []                 =  badHead

badHead :: a
badHead = errorEmptyList "head"

errorEmptyList :: String -> a
errorEmptyList fun =
    error (prel_list_str ++ fun ++ ": empty list")
```

`IOException` concludes most of the ordinary IO exceptions you may have seen in other programming languages, e.g. FileNotFound, NoPermission, UnexpectedEOF etc. It's further extended in [`System.IO.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html) and is only throwed in the context of IO monad.

There are six arithmetic exceptions in `base`, which are

```
data ArithException
  = Overflow
  | Underflow
  | LossOfPrecision
  | DivideByZero
  | Denormal
  | RatioZeroDenominator
```

Two array access exceptions, which are:

```
data ArrayException
  = IndexOutOfBounds    String
  | UndefinedElement    String
```

Four async exceptions, i.e. exceptions designed to be passed between processes, which are:

```
data AsyncException
  = StackOverflow
  | HeapOverflow
  | ThreadKilled
  | UserInterrupt
```

When a computation obviously won't terminate: [`NonTermination`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:NonTermination)
When one or more processes are blocked forever: [`BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar), [`Deadlock`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:Deadlock), etc.
When pattern matching failed (mainly in monads): [`PatternMatchFail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:PatternMatchFail)
When an assertion failed: [`AssertionFailed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:AssertionFailed)

and much, much more.

Comment: Are you sure *most* are implemented by `error`? A whole slew of them come in the much more palatable `throwIO` style.

Comment: @dfeuer yes you are right, I only checked some modules of pure functions but not the modules doing IO. Thanks for your comment.